# An image into three.js scene is blurred on some screen resolutions

Tags: three.js

I try to create some object that a user could able by mouse rotate use Three.js and webgl. It's displaying fine when a screen has a full HD resolution (1960x1080) but when a user screen had resolution roughly 1366x768 object is ugly (blurred). Most notably text on the image.

Originally image has the resolution 1024x748 and the scene has a size roughly 530x270.

Clear - https://ibb.co/0s7W2hk

[image: Clear]

Blurred - https://ibb.co/tzCkq6W (in some cases blur corruption have more influence)

I connect the model to the scene by next code

```
// ...
scene.add({
    genotype: VOLUMETRIC_OBJECT,
    phenotype: MODELLED_MESH,
    data: {
      model: 'assets/FBX 2013/model.FBX',
      position: {
        x: 0,
        y: isMobile ? 0.05 : 0.375,
        z: 0,
      },
      scale: isMobile ? {
        x: 70e-3,
        y: 70e-3,
        z: 70e-3,
      } : {
        x: 75e-3,
        y: 75e-3,
        z: 75e-3,
      },
      name: 'model',
      material: {
        hb_03_label1Model: {
          map: 'assets/mm1.jpg',
          alphaMap: 'assets/mam1.jpg',
          color: 0xffffff,
          specular: new Color(0xffffff),
          shininess: 5,
          transparent: true,
          opacity: 1,
          needsUpdate: true,
        },
        body_hb_03Model: {
          normalMap: 'assets/mnm2.jpg',
          color: 0xaaaaaa,
          specular: new Color(0xFFFFFF),
          opacity: 0.35,
          shininess: 100,
          transparent: true,
          needsUpdate: true,
          normalScale: {
            x: 1,
            y: 1,
          },
        },
        hb_03_leqidoModel: {
          type: MATERIAL__SHADER,
          map: 'assets/mm3.jpg',
          thicknessMap: 'assets/mtm3.jpg',
          specularMap: 'assets/msm3.jpg',
          normalMap: 'assets/mnm3.jpg',
          repeat: [10, 10],
          color: 0xffffff,
          refractionRatio: 0.985,
          reflectivity: 0.15,
          diffuse: new Vector3(1, 0.3, 0.3),
          thicknessColor: new Vector3(0.11, 0.11, 0.11),
          needsUpdate: true,
          uniformsNeedUpdate: true,
        },
        hb_03_cappaModel: {
          color: 0x00AD16,
          needsUpdate: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  (model) => {
    // ...
  },
)
```

Update 1:
In my case when I change mag and min filters to Linear, I have strong sharpness and text not readable, again. 
I think, for the best result, I need to use mag filter as Linear and min filter as LinearMipMapLinearFilter with the generated by myself mipmap.
But, currently, generate custom mipmap so strong for me. I did increase `anisotropy` for texture, and text is displayed acceptable

Comment: try seeing if not generating mipmaps improves the result you want. In https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture look for the `generateMipmaps` flag.

Comment: when I using `texture.generateMipmaps = false` texture is not rendered.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?

Comment: unfortunally not